# PHPStorm error, jQuery not outputting table

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpstorm

I want to write a table to the screen, but I am not sure why this jQuery prototype isn't working. Console gives me no errors, screen is staying blank.

PHPStorm says .append() wants 2 parameters, which I think isn't correct.

```
Club.prototype.parseData = function(data){
    var table = $('.data');
    $.each(data, function(item, i){
        var row = $('<tr></tr>')
        $.each(item, function(i){
           var cell0 = "<td></td>".text(i.id);
           var cell1 = "<td></td>".text(i.homeClub);
           var cell2 = "<td></td>".text(i.awayClub);
           var cell3 = "<td></td>".text(i.ourGoals);
           var cell4 = "<td></td>".text(i.antiGoals);
           row.append(cell0, cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4);
        });
        table.append(row);

    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need second loop, I assume your object look like this:

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    homeClub: "Test 1",
    awayClub: "Test2",
    ourGoals: 1,
    antiGoals: 2
}, {
    id: 2,
    homeClub: "Test 1",
    awayClub: "Test2",
    ourGoals: 1,
    antiGoals: 3
}];
```

then your method:

```
Club.prototype.parseData = function (data) {
    var table = jQuery('.data tbody');

    jQuery.each(data, function (item, i) {
        var row = jQuery('<tr></tr>')
        row.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(i.id));
        row.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(i.homeClub));
        row.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(i.awayClub));
        row.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(i.ourGoals));
        row.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(i.antiGoals));

        table.append(row);
    })
};
```

or if you can't be sure how many cells can be in row

```
Club.prototype.parseData = function (data) {
    var table = jQuery('.data tbody');
    jQuery.each(data, function (item, i) {
        var row = jQuery('<tr></tr>');
        jQuery.each(i, function (a) {
            row.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(i[a]));
        });
        table.append(row);
    });
};
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmTYh/1/)